# USB does not boot when trying to install Linux on my Asus EeeBook X205TA

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-10, bios, operating-systems

I already made this question on the [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753122/cannot-install-lubuntu-on-asus-laptop) community, but had no good answers/help.

So, here I am.

I am trying to install Lubuntu on my Asus EeeBook X205TA that came with Windows 10 Home (32bit) pre-installed.

Here is the information that may help you help me.

BIOS (model X205TAW) options:

[image]

When I press the UEFI: SanDisk option the screen turns black for a second and comes back to the boot menu. Changing the boot order in BIOS does not have any effect.

Here are the things I tried already:

- Intense Googling for solution;
- Used Rufus USB tool and the one suggested by the Ubuntu website to burn the ISO into the stick. I used all the combinations possible with the Rufus software (partition schemes);
- Tried Lubuntu, Ubuntu and Xubuntu (32bit and 64bit) distros, none worked;
- Using the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool the PC boots the USB without problem and enters the Windows Setup;
- Updated the computer bios;
- Tried to install plop boot manager, no success ("Can't get partition information. 144" Error);
- Tried with several USB sticks and ports (BIOS do not recognize the micro SD slot, even with the distro in it);
- Disabled the secure boot menu. Basically, I tried almost every combination possible in the BIOS settings. The only thing I didn't touch was the Key Management sector;
- Updated the drivers of the computer;
- Made a full reset of the Windows 10, using the Windows 10 tool.

These are the things I remember, if I remember more I will update the question. Any extra information, just ask. I will be online for the next couple hours.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE 04/05/2016**

I've made it work. Sort of. WiFi and sound drivers not working. I ended up reinstalling Windows 10 back...

So, following the suggestions on the answer of @TomaszS, and some crazy tweaking by my part.

Here is what I did:

- Downloaded the 64-bit version of Xubuntu (worked with Ubuntu also);
- Used Rufus to put the distro into an USB stick, using GPT partition mode;
- Downloaded [this](https://github.com/hirotakaster/baytail-bootia32.efi) and [this](http://www.thinktwisted.com/gradschool/Public/grubia32.efi);
- Copied both to the boot/EFI folder on the USB stick that I was using;
- Copied the same files on the previous step again and changed the names of it to the original ones. The ones that came with the Ubuntu/Xubuntu download, so it would replace these files (32-bit versions instead of 64-bit) for the installation (I guess, don't really know. It just worked);
- Delete the original files on the boot/EFI folder;
- Deactivate the secure boot etc. to make it boot from the USB;
- Let the installation download updates during the install;
- Wait to complete and that is it!

---

**UPDATE 05/06/2017**

Finally got it to work with Arch Linux and a little bit of wiki reading. Following these guides I made it work (SOUND DOES NOT WORK, unfortunately):

- [Arch Linux X205TA wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Asus_x205ta);
- [Installing Arch Linux on Asus X205TA - Ifran's blog](http://ifranali.blogspot.com.br/2015/04/installing-arch-linux-on-asus-x205ta.html);
- [Arch Linux on Asus X205TA](https://github.com/gtbjj/x205ta). I used the ISO provided by this guide with not many problems. Remember you should take care when using things from the internet...

If you give these guides a good read you will get an Arch Linux running (withou sound). As far as Ubuntu goes, not sure if it is possible.

Comment: In the Boot options menu, do you have anything other than UEFI?

Comment: I have the Windows Boot option. Like in this pic http://i.imgur.com/Iex2DH1g.jpg

Comment: Yes, I already saw that pic. I meant, if there are any other options for `Boot Option #1`

Comment: There is just the disable and Windows Boot Manager options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After years, I will finally answer my own question. I've created an updated tutorial on how to install Arch on this machine. I did not test with other distros, but the gig should be the same. Check this GitHub [repo](https://github.com/meyer1994/x205ta) for the tutorial. The guide is copied below:

### Getting started

You will need:

- USB flash drive
- Another linux machine
- Arch Linux [ISO](https://archlinux.org/download/)

Older images did not have WIFI or sound working out of the box. However, newer
images are working correctly. There are still some [quirks](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016142109/https://github.com/avakyeramian/Asus_X205TA_Debian_Fix) to deal,
however.

### Pre install

#### `bootia32.efi`

First of all, you will need to create a `bootia32.efi` for yourself. You'll
neeed a new `grub.cfg` file. Luckily, I have one, copied from
this [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803060417/https://ifranali.blogspot.com/2015/04/installing-arch-linux-on-asus-x205ta.html) and it is included in this repo.

You **MUST** change the `ARCH_YYYYMM` label in the `grub.cfg` file to match the
ISO you have just downloaded. To get the correct label for the ISO you just
downloaded you can execute the following (line breaks added):

```sh
$ file archlinux-2021.10.01-x86_64.iso
archlinux-2021.10.01-x86_64.iso:
    ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data (DOS/MBR boot sector)
    'ARCH_202110' (bootable)
```

After you have updated the `grub.cfg` file to match your ISO, you can execute
the following:

```sh
$ grub-mkstandalone -v \
    -d /usr/lib/grub/i386-efi/ \
    -O i386-efi \
    --modules='part_gpt part_msdos' \
    --fonts=unicode \
    --locales=uk \
    --themes='' \
    -o ./bootia32.efi \
    /boot/grub/grub.cfg=./grub.cfg
```

This will generate a `bootia32.efi` file on your current directory.

#### Booting USB

This step is very easy. We are just going to copy all files from the ISO to a
USB flash drive and add our `bootia32.efi` file. First, format it using `vfat`
and set the label of the drive to match the Arch Linux ISO label. In our
example, it was `ARCH_202110`.

```sh
$ mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdc1 -n ARCH_202110
```

Mount it, so we can copy files to it:

```sh
$ mkdir /tmp/usb
$ mount /dev/sdc1 /tmp/usb
```

Mount the ISO file as well, so we can copy its files:

```sh
$ mkdir /tmp/iso
$ mount archlinux-2021.10.01-x86_64.iso /tmp/iso -o loop
mount: /tmp/iso: WARNING: source write-protected, mounted read-only.
```

Copy all files from ISO to USB, add our `bootia32.efi` as well:

```sh
$ cp -rv /tmp/iso/* /tmp/usb
$ cp -v bootia32.efi /tmp/usb/EFI/BOOT/
```

Clean up after yourself:

```sh
$ umount /tmp/iso
$ umount /tmp/usb
```

You have a bootable USB!!

### Install

To boot into the USB media just press `ESC`, or `F2` multiple times while the
computer is booting. Make sure you have "secure boot" deactivated in the BIOS.

Newer versions of arch linux installation medias come with a very handy script
that helps with the installation process. First, connect to the internet using
[`iwctl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd#iwctl):

```sh
$ iwctl
[iwd]# station wlan0 scan
[iwd]# station wlan0 connect YOUR_WIFI
[iwd]# exit
```

Here I show the summary of my installation, which worked. You can modify it to
better suit your case.

```sh
$ archinstall
Select one of the above keyboard languages: us-acentos
Select one of the above regions to download packages from: United states
Select one of the above disks: /dev/mmcblk2
Found partitions on the selected drive: Format entire drive and setup a basic partition scheme
Select which filesystem your main partition should use: ext4
Enter disk encryption password (leave blank for no encryption):
Would you like to use GRUB as a bootloader: y
Desired hostname for installation: x205ta
Enter root password:
Enter a username: meyer1994
Password for user meyer1994:
Should this user be a supeuser: y
Enter a pre-programmed profile name: minimal
Choose which kernels to use: linux
Write additional packages to install:
Select one network interface to configure:
Enter a valid timezone: Brazil/East
Would you like automatic time synchronization: y
```

Wait for it to finish but do not restart.

### Post install

After you finished the installation process, while still in using the bootable
USB, [`chroot`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Chroot) into the system. Usually, the system will be mounted in
`/mnt`. If not, mount them first and then `chroot` into it:

```sh
$ mount /dev/mmcblk2p2 /mnt
$ mount /dev/mmcblk2p1 /mnt/boot
$ arch-chroot /mnt
```

#### Install grub

We need to install a correct version of grub into this system.

```sh
$ grub-install \
    -–target=i386-efi \
    -–efi-directory=/boot \
    --bootloader-id=grub_uefi \
    -–recheck
Installing for i386-efi partition
Installation finished. No errors reported
```

#### Generate `grub.cfg`

And generate its configuration:

```sh
$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file
...
done
```

#### Audio

Audio was a known issue with this machine. However, it seems to have been
resolved in newer linux kernel versions. To make it work, I just installed
`pulseaudio` and rebooted the computer.

```sh
$ pacman -S pulseaudio
```

### Thanks

- ifranali's [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803060417/https://ifranali.blogspot.com/2015/04/installing-arch-linux-on-asus-x205ta.html): the main reference for this
- Arch Wiki X205TA [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ASUS_x205ta): gathering lots of info
- savagezen's [repo](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016143553/https://github.com/savagezen/x205ta): used by me the first time I got this working, back in
  2016
- [Myself](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016143503/https://superuser.com/questions/1071080/usb-does-not-boot-when-trying-to-install-linux-on-my-asus-eeebook-x205ta): for making a question in 2016, which I forgot, and leading me
  back to ifranali's blog
- [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/): for having a snapshot of ifranali's blog
- avakyeramian's [repo](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016142109/https://github.com/avakyeramian/Asus_X205TA_Debian_Fix): for having some fixes to problems I did not even
  know existed

Answer (score 4):

I looked up your processor and it is actually a 64-bit processor. The thing with these smaller netbooks that have a intel baytrail is that they often have 64-bit processors but 32-bit UEFI firmware. Basically you need a 64-bit Linux distro with a 32-bit bootloader for it to work because as far as I know, 32-bit Ubuntu doesn't have an .EFI file and the 64-bit Ubuntu doesn't have a 32-bit .EFI.

This is what I had to do for mine:
http://liliputing.com/2013/10/booting-ubuntu-asus-transformer-book-t100.html

You need use this 32-bit bootia32.efi boot file: https://github.com/hirotakaster/baytail-bootia32.efi and put in in `EFI/BOOT/bootia32.efi` on your 64-bit live USB drive for it to work.

It's really a pain in the butt. I ended up just sticking with windows 10 and running lubuntu in virtualbox because support wasn't that great for my T100TAF.

Comment: I will try it right away and post the results!

Comment: Yeah. It fixed the boot problem but... http://imgur.com/JelvF9o

Comment: New problem http://imgur.com/A1EiPSX

Comment: GRUB is trying to install the 64-bit bootloader from the live CD which won't work. You need to somehow install that bootia32.efi file with grub. I'm not quite certain about the CLI commands.

Comment: Try this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206274/how-do-i-repair-grub2-not-booting-32-bit-efi-on-a-64-bit-machine

Answer (score -1):

I am using MX Linux 19 in an old Asus EeeBook X205TA and it’s working well & the OS setup is working out of the box, Boot, installation ..etc. 
To update the Network wireless driver, Bluetooth, Headphone jack , just follow the instructions provided in this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2379657
Note: To configure the drivers, you can connect your Android mobile to the laptop thru USB cable “Threading” in order to get connected to the internet (haven’t tried Iphone).