# how to boot from USB on i-life zedbook tablet?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, bios

I want to install Ubuntu on my i-life Zedbook tablet. It is dual boot (windows 10 & Android 5.1). I created the bootable USB for Ubuntu but I can't boot from the USB. I explored everywhere but there isn't any USB option to choose in BIOS (UEFI). Below you can find the boot menu images.

[image: Boot]

[image: Boot Manager]

Comment: You have the USB boot enabled. Have you made the USB bootable properly? Have you tried booting from some other device?

Comment: yes i did and it worked well

Comment: This question might be helpful to you.. http://superuser.com/q/1071080/467175

Comment: i did the same and copy the 32 bit bootloader to bootable USB, so i could boot from the USB and see the grub but when I hit the try ubuntu just screen turn black and nothing happen

Comment: How i can find the proper 32 bit bootloader for my i-life zedbook G?